# How to click on a button with Selenium and Java?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, iframe, webdriverwait

I am trying to click on the "NO THANKS" in the iframe but keep getting "Expected condition failed: waiting for frame to be available"

My code:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
                                    
driver.get("http://www.qaclickacademy.com");

new WebDriverWait(driver,40).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt
(By.xpath("//div[@class='sumome-react-wysiwyg-popup-animation-group']")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='sumome-react-wysiwyg-popup-animation-group']/span/div/div[6]/div//div/button")).click();
```

It does take some time for the iframe to popup after initial load of page but I had wait at 20,30,40 and 60 and it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element isn't with in any `<iframe>`.

To click on the element <kbd>NO THANKS</kbd> you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("http://www.qaclickacademy.com")
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[text()='NO THANKS']"))).click();
  ```